# Is it a good way to put a static api key and match it with the request in header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I have added a static ApiKey like this into the web.config file and when the user requests our web API they need to pass the ApiKey named key-value and if that matches then proceed else 401 error.

Is this a correct way to authenticate?

```
 public List<Models.TasksList> Get(string module)
        {
            var re = Request;
            var headers = re.Headers;
            headers.Add("ApiKey", "");

            string[] arr= headers.GetValues("ApiKey").ToArray();

            string storedApiKey = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"]);

            if (arr[0].Trim() != storedApiKey.Trim())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }
               //Other code to process
}
```

Comment: nope bcoz every one can sniff that api key out of you're requests. If it's to track api users then it's fine, but if you're using it to authorize user's actions then no, and you should switch to a more sophosticated authentication scheme....

Comment: Are you on Azure with that api or do you host yourself? Maybe have a look at [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)?

Comment: @Fildor host on our own server. On IIS>

Comment: @mahdimahzouni alright, I am too new to this, it's my first day to this. Can you guide me on some good but easy to follow and learn scheme since? since I am using OData based WebAPI.

Comment: You never want to send a Private key along with the data that it was used to encrypt!!!

Comment: @jdweng can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: yeah man no worries, if you're looking for a way then look up user management and oauth with identity server and asp identity system. if you just want to limit api calls or something similar then you can issue api keys.

Comment: "if you just want to limit api calls or something similar then you can issue api keys". Means the way I am doing?

Comment: Do not put the private key into the request.  It is a security violation.